# Undelete Hidden Features of Delphi IDE, some answers are helpful and question should be kept alive

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Recently some well-known Delphi bloggers [posted](http://delphi.org/2014/02/hidden-features-in-the-delphi-object-pascal-language/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:%20DelphiDotOrg%20%28Delphi.org%29) [copies](http://wiert.me/2014/02/20/hidden-features-in-delphi-related-topics-from-stackoverflow-until-the-diamond-moderators-kill-these-too/) of [high-voted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063274/hidden-features-in-the-delphi-language) [Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1745772/hidden-features-of-oxygene) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102254/hidden-features-of-the-delphi-ide) that were being flagged for deletion in order to save the material for the community. Thankfully, since then there seem to have been enough reopen votes cast to keep two of those three questions alive for the time being.

These were questions in the "Hidden features of..." series that are [generally closed but not deleted, where even that response is highly debated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56669/should-hidden-features-of-x-be-removed-closed-locked).  Consensus seems to be that this series of questions are outside the original Stack Overflow scope, but are often [useful questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56669/should-hidden-features-of-x-be-removed-closed-locked), and that questions in general should only be deleted ["as a last resort or for really bad posts"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/50603/163697).

(This change in SO from religious deletion to being more open about the rules for useful resources is a great thing, and I think a sign of the growing maturity of SO as a site. It's something I'm very grateful for.)

However, [the third question I linked to seems to have been deleted anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102254/hidden-features-of-the-delphi-ide), some time ago, before these bloggers noticed and made backups. I don't know of its quality, because it's deleted.

I do know that [similar questions related to the same language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063274/hidden-features-in-the-delphi-language) and [the same question about other environments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146297/hidden-features-of-xcode) had some very interesting replies, so it's likely this question either did, or would have, useful answers were it open.

Is it possible to undelete it, please?

---

**Update:** It turns out that the question had been reopened, but not undeleted - [possibly a bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222656/163697). But it's also clear that (a) this question is lower-quality than similar questions (something invisible to me when I asked), and (b) there's still disagreement about the value of "Hidden Features of..." posts at all. (I linked to some of the discussions above, showing they were now accepted, but some commenters below think differently. Ie, there is no community agreement.)

Re (a), it is clear from similar questions that this question has the potential to have high-quality answers. [**I have asked for input from the Delphi community.**](http://itinerantdeveloper.blogspot.ro/2014/02/hidden-features-of-delphi-ide-on-stack.html) Would you leave the question open long enough for this to have an effect, please? I genuinely think there is potential in this question.

Re (b), I don't personally understand the combination of "not acceptable answers" yet "being kept around for their value". It's a paradox. @animuson phrases it that it's about the question not the answers: "[the community] think the answers are useful and have value, even though the question does not meet our standards" - again something I find a paradox. If a question produces good answers, it is a good question. If something producing good results does not meet the standards, the standards need to be examined to accommodate something that produces good results. After all, Stack Overflow is meant to be a resource - a useful body of knowledge. We should not delete the knowledge just because whatever prompted that knowledge to be written down was "bad".

Thankyou to @Shog for undeleting. If in a while the question is still bad quality, I will support closing (not deleting) it again. Please give it a little time [for us to improve it](http://itinerantdeveloper.blogspot.ro/2014/02/hidden-features-of-delphi-ide-on-stack.html) though.

---

**Update 2:** This question has been locked, so neither I nor anyone else can make some of the improvements we want to. (It was locked by @animuson, a mod who has read this thread and is aware I am trying to improve the question and its answers. A well as providing answers from material new in the past few years - requiring adding new answers - I would like edit the question to follow suggestions made by @Josh Caswell (thanks) in a comment below. Both these have been prevented. I am not sure this is in the spirit of SO.)

Moreover, since I asked this question,

- a related question got [**deleted**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063274/hidden-features-in-the-delphi-language)
- another related question is [**on hold**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1745772/hidden-features-of-oxygene)
- and another question I mentioned as a good example is now [**locked**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146297/hidden-features-of-xcode).

**I am very much afraid that in trying to get a reopened question undeleted and then improving it, I have inadvertently done great damage to other useful questions.**

I should point out that [the deletions here are inconsistent with treatment of other questions in the same series.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56669/should-hidden-features-of-x-be-removed-closed-locked)

We are supposed to be collaboratively *improving* things here.

Comment: Recent (though unproductive) [discussion about this question's deletion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222285/could-you-moderators-stop-deleting-community-wiki-questions).

Comment: You're right, that discussion was unproductive! Maybe we can have a better one :) I tried to set up this question for a productive discussion, linking to many previous and related MSO pages. (And, [more insight on deletionism in general here.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124439/community-led-deletionism-a-protocol-for-sanity) Note the highest-voted answer - ouch! And I think a reason why SO policies have thankfully changed.)

Comment: If you delete all those answers that are documented, what do you actually have left?

Comment: @random I already addressed that: "If in a while the question is still bad quality, I will support closing (not deleting) it again. Please give it a little time [for us to improve it](http://itinerantdeveloper.blogspot.ro/2014/02/hidden-features-of-delphi-ide-on-stack.html) though." Remember the question had its content invisible to me when I asked it be restored, and that this series of questions have been of high Delphi community interest the past few days due to attention being called to deletion.

Comment: David, note that the question is still closed. You'll be able to edit existing answers, but not add new ones.

Comment: The time for you to improve it is when it's _closed_, so that it can't accrue _more_ cruft. Everything can be edited while the question is closed and/or deleted.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta Didn't it get reopened *and* undeleted? That's what Shog's screenshot shows.  Unless reopening is not the same is undoing it being closed? Do I misunderstand something?

Comment: David, it was reopened, undeleted, then closed again.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta Crikey. People are ruthless, aren't they!

Comment: What do you mean, David? Do you really think the question should stay open? It's absolutely not a question that fits on this site, as we've learned through hard experience.

Comment: @Michael Problem solved.

Comment: @animuson Does locking it really help? It was reopened two days ago, rapidly got reopen votes just now, and I [posted for the community to help bring it up to scratch](http://itinerantdeveloper.blogspot.ro/2014/02/hidden-features-of-delphi-ide-on-stack.html) and asked above it be given time to for that to happen.  Half an hour isn't time.  A few days at least, please? Aren't we supposed to *collaboratively improve* things here?

Comment: @DavidM That lock only locks the question. You're free to edit any of the answers as you see fit. Enjoy.

Comment: @animuson That's something, I guess.  But four year's worth of new material? How do we add that?

Comment: Headings/descriptive text for individual answers, and an index in the question body, as in [Hidden features of Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/101268), might be a good place to start the editing task. That would start to make things searchable.

Comment: Thanks @JoshCaswell - I appreciate the pointer :)

Comment: Actually @JoshCaswell I can't do that, since the question is locked and I can only edit answers, not the question. (The "edit" link is disabled.) Other odd stuff is happening too: comments are vanishing, for example. I don't know what's going on.

Comment: @DavidM I went through and deleted all the useless "thanks I didn't know that" comments. I also deleted some answers which repeated things already said in better answers, or didn't answer the question at all.

Comment: @animuson That's great, a good start to help improve it.  Thanks!  I'd really like to be able to add new material though too :)  (In the morning, since it's almost midnight here.)

Comment: @animuson Could you respond to the questions please? For example, how do we add four year's worth of new answers when it's locked? How do I or anyone else follow Josh Caswell's advice to edit the question, when it's locked and can't be edited? Why is the question closed when it's in the middle of being edited and improved? Why are related *inarguably* high-quality questions being deleted? Why is your [response](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222656/163697) that it was reopened to play with a SO bug, not because community members blogged about the post's value? Isn't something very wrong here?

Comment: @DavidM The question is not on-topic here, there's nothing to argue about with that. You are being given a chance to improve the existing content to be useful in order to prevent it being deleted again, **not add new content**. If the existing content can't be improved or is not useful enough to be salvaged, then it should be deleted. It's that simple.

Comment: @animuson 1. I can't improve the question *per above recommendations* because you locked it. If I opened another question, it would be rightfully closed as a duplicate. 2. Why are other high quality questions being deleted, inconsistently with SO's normal stance? You haven't addressed that at all. 3. Also unaddressed: Do you seriously think that five reputable users reopened the question to play with a SO bug, and not because members of the language community outside SO mentioned the deletion in blog posts, prompting attention? That is *extremely* disrespectful and completely out of line.

Comment: @DavidM Why don't you concentrate on improving the answers first, and if you can complete that, I'll unlock the question so you can create the index you so desire.

Comment: @animuson Please answer my other questions and your very concerning attitude towards other SO members.

Comment: Re: your update, [Hidden features of Oxygene](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1745772) has been viewed 788 times in its four-year existence, and that's counting the two views that I just made because I accidentally closed the tab instead of copying the URL.  No more than 35 of those viewers felt it was worth voting on the question or any of the answers. Let it go.

Comment: All of the answers to "Hidden features of Delphi IDE" are still editable; the question lock doesn't affect that.

Comment: @JoshCaswell - how do I read that? As niche languages being unimportant in SO? I know not many people use Oxygene but is that a good reason to close it? Quite the opposite: it's these unusual but actively developed languages that can have some of the most unusual features. And yes, I know I can edit the answers (and have edited some) but I can't post good content, I can't split answers up where one answer covers many things, and I can't follow your advice about organisation.

Comment: The argument for keeping a question that are manifestly unsuited for the site is its [historical signficance/popularity](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587/what-is-a-historical-lock-and-what-is-it-used-for); it's a courtesy. [Small user bases don't](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220767/) change the fact that [the question doesn't fit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195772/). I know you can't make the index for "HFoDI", but there's a lot of work to be done on the answers, too. Best of luck.

Comment: It's not manifestly unsuited because [there is a lot of disagreement about their deletion at all](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56669/should-hidden-features-of-x-be-removed-closed-locked) - in fact the two highest answers on that question end up supporting them. If the question is kept around for high user bases then [small user bases should not change that](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220767/) - as you yourself linked. This family of questions are all locked and retained as high value but no longer to be newly asked. All. Please don't go deleting high-quality posts!

Comment: Also, please read [this question.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124439/community-led-deletionism-a-protocol-for-sanity?rq=1) It may save a lot of argument if we're all on the same page.

Comment: Also [this question.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56669/should-hidden-features-of-x-be-removed-closed-locked)

Comment: I've read 'em. I was a participant in the discussions^Wfistfights that led up to CLD:APfS. See my comments there?

Comment: @JoshCaswell What is CLD:APFS?

Comment: Community Led Deletionism: A Protocol for Sanity

Comment: @DavidM: *"This question has been locked, so neither I nor anyone else can make some of the improvements we want to."* - No, you can edit and improve the existing answers.

Comment: @sth: But I can't split answers where one covers several things. I can't edit the question as I was directly suggested. And I can't add good answers. If I split answers, I'll end up deleting a lot of material because I have nowhere to put the second (or third) items.

Comment: @sth Can you tell me how to address those issues, please?

Answer (score 10):

I've undeleted it, for the simple reason that **the community here already re-opened it**:

[image: reopened 2 days ago]

I'm not entirely clear on why the system allowed it to be reopened without being undeleted first - frankly, that seems like a bug to me. But, *reopening is supposed to stop deletion* so that's that.

*That being said*, I'm not at all convinced this question needs to stick around:

> Source for 80% of "hidden" features described in answers is [Keyboard mapping index](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Keyboard_Mappings_Index) –  [ThinkJet Aug 15 '11 at 16:00](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102254/hidden-features-of-the-delphi-ide#comment8455047_102254)
>
> This list of hidden features is kinda lame. Most answers aren't "hidden" features at all. They are just regurgitation of Delphi's **fully documented** features. –  [Kenneth Cochran Nov 19 '10 at 16:39](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102254/hidden-features-of-the-delphi-ide#comment4574733_102254)

This is sadly typical of these "hidden features" threads, which is why folks here soured on them over the years (they were once *well-loved* by many): in the absence of a large number of *truly obscure* features, they end up just turning into lists of *everyone's favorite things about X*.

If you see something of lasting value in that thread, I recommend you do something to highlight it. Otherwise, I don't see it lasting very long.

Comment: I have a feeling it was only reopened because the community is fascinated with the bug that they can reopen deleted questions but can't close deleted questions. It's been done before.

Comment: @animuson I didn't know that was possible. I think it's most likely it was reopened because of the recent attention drawn to it by two community bloggers.

Comment: @animuson you mean, guys were simply exploring _hidden features of Stack Overflow_?

Answer (score 8):

The particular question you linked is most of all **horribly organized**. In comparison to other "Hidden Features" questions on Stack Overflow, this one looks like the dumpster in the alley that the homeless try to pick scraps out of for food. Most of the answers are simply list of random and unrelated key-combination commands, and there is quite a bit of repetition between answers. As others have said before, apparently a lot of these aren't even *hidden* but can easily be found in the documentation.

I honestly think it should remain deleted, but apparently Shog disagrees.

Comment: I can't see that, because I can't see the content, because it's deleted not closed. But my response would be, we've seen how the same question elsewhere can be great. Let's improve this one.

Comment: @DavidM Shog undeleted it, so you can see it. ;)

Comment: Great! Thanks @Shog. Now, let's try to improve the answer quality and make the question the resource it should be.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta: The accepted answer being an easter egg isn't great. Some of the others are interesting, though. Look at [the same question about a different IDE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/146297/hidden-features-of-xcode) - there is a lot of potential for a useful resource. As a community (IMO) we should improve it, not delete it. Nevertheless, thanks for undeleting it, and I will make a blog post asking for some high-quality answers to promote it somewhat. Hopefully it will be better, soon.

Comment: @David, while interesting, the community has decided that question like these aren't on-topic. They're usually closed. I suggest you grab the content you like, and build a blog (or blog series!) out of them. The [SE license](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) is pretty friendly about that.

Comment: "Hidden features" always end up being "Post chunks of the documentation and we'll vote"

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta Are you sure that's the case? I linked to several MSO pages showing [they should be left open.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56669/should-hidden-features-of-x-be-removed-closed-locked) Seems to be quite some debate about it.

Comment: @random Yep. Looking at the Q now it's reopened, I agree. However, it is now my mission to improve it.

Comment: @DavidM That discussion is from 2010. Did you actually look at any of the questions, though? They are all closed and most that still exist are historically locked. That's a pretty clear indication to others that they are *not* acceptable questions. They're just being kept around for their value.

Comment: No, Shog and you agree. He just undeleted it because it wasn't closed. As a moderator, you have the power to both close and delete it so it's not sitting there opened yet deleted, which really does seem like a bug. :) Although I'd wait until everyone forgets about it again...

Comment: I didn't say not acceptable *answers*. I said it's not an acceptable *question*. The community wants to keep them around, though, because they think the *answers* are useful and have value, even though the *question* does not meet our standards.

Comment: It wouldn't be a source of frustration for casual (or non-casual) users if problematic questions stayed deleted and thus invisible, @DavidM. Archive this stuff off-site (sounds like most of it already _is_ available off-site), and stop dragging dead horses out of their shallow graves to get spit on again.

Comment: @JoshCaswell I don't understand, sorry. Do you mean deleted answers should go away completely, not even a sign they were ever there? The frustration (I believe) is because of the policies not the questions, btw, and hiding questions that demonstrate the policies is probably the wrong response to dissatisfaction with the policies.

Comment: Yes, hard deletion is undesirable, @DavidM; my point is that casual users would not be upset about SO not hosting this information if it were just left invisible, cleaned up, and moved off-site. What we have right now is a ghoul: an old, dead shambles of a question. You yourself are using other (slightly better-kept) questions of this kind to justify giving this six-year-old mess another chance. Then next time someone uses this one to justify re-opening their favorite, and we have the same argument all over again. We should just let them go. The idea was tried, and it doesn't fit on this site.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Sadly, the fact it was a mess was invisible - because it was deleted. Round and round we go :( Surely, closing and letting the community edit and fix it up is better?

Comment: It was around for four years before it was even _closed_, and then another year before deletion, @DavidM: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/102254/revisions How much time do you need?

Comment: @JoshCaswell Enough to know it exists. I didn't see it before. I've only ever seen dead links to it.

Answer (score 4):

It's now been over two months since this call to arms; in that time, exactly two of the answers have been edited, by you. They're nice edits, but still, nothing else has been done.

The lock on the question itself, [which you complained made improvement impossible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222654/undelete-hidden-features-of-delphi-ide-some-answers-are-helpful-and-question-sh?lq=1#comment724631_222654), was removed two weeks ago. Previous to this discussion, the collection was around, in its lackluster state, [for four years before it was closed](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/102254/revisions) and languished for a further year before deletion. [Very little editing took place](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/102254/timeline) during that year, either.

The question is [a so-called "list question"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124450/what-is-the-definition-of-a-list-question), unsuitable for the site because, among other things -- [as Shog pointed out several years ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/57369/159251) -- they create horrible search targets.

It looks like no one, including you, has enough interest in the post to polish it to the point where [a historical lock is justified](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587/what-is-a-historical-lock-and-what-is-it-used-for), on [the model of similar list questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101268/hidden-features-of-python).

It's time to let this one go; it doesn't fit here, and it's not Stack Overflow's responsibility to host it. The contents are [freely re-usable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/24618/159251) by you or anyone else, and won't be [truly gone even when the post is in the "deleted" state](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/159251).

Comment: No-one including me? I was very interested, and tried - and as you know, the question was locked, preventing the kinds of edits SO, including you, advised me to make. I advertised among other Delphi developers, several of whom saw what happened and threw up their hands too. It's nice you removed the lock a couple of week ago, but I wasn't notified so - of course - I haven't made any further action. I'm not sure why or how you would expect me to know it had its status changed.

Comment: Sadly, the attitude here when I originally asked was very unhelpful and I and others were actively prevented from fixing it. (I understand disagreement, but not actively preventing someone fixing a question. The discussion around how to fix it with this barrier in place was a great example of bureaucracy, going round and round in circles. 'You can do X'. 'But it prevents X'. '[Response ignoring the problem] Just do X, don't complain.') It was very shameful, I think, and reflected very badly on the SO community. I even followed it up in meta trying to inspire a helpful attitude change, but...

Comment: I have now mostly given up on SO and return occasionally to vote questions or answers, but I am no longer interested in community participation. I probably also won't modify this particular question. Please delete it, as in fact I asked months ago too.

Comment: @DavidM, bravo for your efforts. SO has gone terribly authoritarian, abusively so. You are not alone in having given up on SO community and return occasionally solely for selfish reasons.

Comment: Josh, the central point is that a straitjacket of rules will not fit any community. There has to be some amount of tolerance. While this Delphi one is not a good example, the Eclipse one is a veritable treasure trove. And, you can see the moderator Robert Harvey being forced to invoke a demonstrably false reason "will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion". There is not a single statement of debate or argument, or even polling other than the votes that are inherent in SO. Why and how can a moderator essentially "lie" in order to do this?